# Como fazer com que toque uma música quando o usuário colocar o mouse em cima de um elemento?

Tags: javascript, html

É possível que quando o usuário passar o cursor sobre determinado elemento no site, uma música tocasse? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode combinar o `onmouseover` com o elemento `<audio>`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("musica"); 

function mouseOver() { 
    x.play(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="musica">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<h1 onmouseover="mouseOver()">Iniciar musica</h1>
```

Comment: Isso é java Script?

Comment: Muito bom cara!

Comment: @ViniciusBorgesLima É uai kkkk

Comment: É que minha professora me proibiu de usar javaScript kk

Answer (score 3):

**Com Play e Pause:**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
    x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    x.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="http://musicasitalianas.com/fileMP3/innobra.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
  Seu browser não suporta audio.
</audio>

<image src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Play-Normal-icon.png" width="64" height="64" onmouseover="playAudio()">
<image src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Pause-Normal-icon.png" width="64" height="64"onmouseover="pauseAudio()">
```

> [Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play)

**Com controles**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
x.controls = false;
function reproduzir() { 
    x.controls = true;
    x.load();
    x.play();
    document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://musicasitalianas.com/fileMP3/innobra.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Seu browser não suporta audio.
</audio>

<image id="img" src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Play-Normal-icon.png" width="32" height="32" onmouseover="reproduzir()">
```